# Integrity check failed for "anymatch" (computed integrity doesn't match our records, got

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I have a node.js project (Nest JS to be more specific), where i am trying to reinstall my depdency after getting the same error as described below.

I have not seen something like this before. I checked the `yarn.lock` and `pacakge.json` files nd the `anymatch` dependency is only listed as dependencies to other dependencies (as shown in image 2)

Has anybody experienced something like this before?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I came across the same problem but with other package.
Try this:

```
yarn cache clean
yarn --update-checksums
yarn install
```